# Compare two CSV files of different length

Tags: csv, unix, compare

I have two CSV files with different no of records. I have to compare column 1 of file1 with column 1 of file2 if it matches then print only those lines from file2 where column 2 does not match.
Need a help to do this using Unix command.

Comment: Can you give some example data?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add example input files and the expected output. Format input and output data as code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to post a solution without example data but you could try the following awk example none the less:

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR { map[$2]=1;next } { if (map[$2]!=1) { print } }' file1.csv file2.csv
```

Set the field separator to comma with -F. Process the first file first (NR==FNR), create an array called map with the second comma separated field as the index. Then when processing the second file, if there is no entry in map for the second field, print the line.